# Counter Not Incrementing

Tags: counters, amsart

I'm trying to typeset a document in amsart and I wasn't familiar with the counter used for sections, so I just redefined the section environment to try to get the look I'm going for... unfortunately, the way I've defined the environment, the counter doesn't seem to increment.

The MWE is

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcounter{thesection}
\renewenvironment{section}[1]
{{\centering\Huge {\refstepcounter{thesection}\thesection. #1}\par}}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{Text}    
    \section{More Text}
\end{document}
```

Have I defined something incorrectly? And is there a more efficient way to get the look I'm going for here?

Comment: you need to type `\thethesection`. `\thesection` print the value of `section` counter that is defined by ams class. But this is not the correct way to redefine `\section` style.

Comment: `section` is not an environment, so using `\renewenvironment` is perhaps a bit strange.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: This is what happens when a mathematician is left to tinker on a LaTeX project by his adviser... :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\Huge\scshape\centering}}        %%<<<----       Remove \scshape if you want, Originally we have \normalfont which is replaced by `\Huge.
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
    \section{Text}
    \section{More Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Same in a surgical way using `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\scshape}{\Huge}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{Text}
    \section{More Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the initial response, is there a particular reason one uses the lengthy commands there? I'm not extremely acquainted with this aspect of latex, and it usually takes me a while to understand what each part is doing. (The second response seems to be much easier to understand.) +1

Comment: @Clayton: Search for the `\section` command in `amsart.cls` and fiddle with it. This is how `amsart` defines `\section` and we have to follow its style. Note that other packages, used for section styling, like `sectsty` and `titlesec` are not that friendly with `amsart` class.

Comment: @Clayton apart from the environment error you redefinition removes most of the `\section` functionality, the `*` form tables of contents, indentation etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I appreciate the insight. I'm doing this for a (small?) presentation, so I only need ~15 transparencies. I'm going for fashion over function in this context, but I'll keep in mind what you've said for future reference.

Comment: @Clayton -- before `xpatch` existed (before 2012), the only way to change a command that allows optional arguments was to redefine the whole thing -- the "lengthy command" as you call it.  even using `xpatch`, it's still necessary to understand the "long form" so that the intended adjustment is made properly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Do you have a suggested reference to learn the "long form"? I see it implemented almost every time I ask a question or reference a question on this site, and I'm guilty of typically copy/pasting and tweaking until something works the way I want it to work...

Comment: probably the most easily digestible description is in section 2.2.2 of the latex companion, "formatting headings".  the code explication of `\@startsection` is in the file source2e.pdf (`texdoc source2e` on a tex live installation) in section 61.2 "sectioning".  for specifics in the ams document classes, `texdoc amsclass`, sections 2.14 "redefined internal sectioning commands" and 2.15 "chapters and sections". (none of this is easy going, but instructive if you want to learn the underlying details.)